# Problems appear after I run "pod install" in terminal

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation, flutter-test

This is the problem:

[image: This is the problem]

What should I do? Because of this I can't open the simulator and when I write flutter run It doesn't work and writes 'could not build the application for the simulator. error launching application' on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Delete Pods folder

Delete Podfile.lock

Delete .symlinks folder

Now try pod install with `arch -x86_64 pod install`

Edit

```dart
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '11.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Comment: Except now I can't turn the simulator on. Nothing change!!

Comment: Please post your pod file here

Comment: # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Runner' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Runner

end

Comment: If you don't mind, contact me on Instagram, I will send you pictures of the problem

Comment: Edited my answer. Please use this pod file

Comment: Thanks, the problem is solved!!! I have several days of suffering because of it, thanks to you, you are my savior. Thanks again

Comment: Cool. Please accept The answer if it helped. It will be helpful for others with same issue

Comment: I'm new here when I get 15 reputations I will do it